# getting sqLiteException when useing getContentResolver().query()

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to get data from sqlite database.Tried using this`context.getContentResolver().query()` method and I got following SqlException

```
near ":23": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT wol_wait, mac_addr, _id, address, name, wol_port, user, timeout, pass FROM hosts WHERE (mac_addr=00:23:15:97:ce:a0) ORDER BY name ASC
```

this is the code that I’m using

```
Cursor c=context.getContentResolver().query(HostProvider.Hosts.CONTENT_URI,null, Hosts.MAC_ADDR +"=" +String.valueOf(mhost.mac_addr),null,HostProvider.Hosts.NAME + " ASC");
```

how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals such as MAC addresses need to be in `'single quotes'`, or better yet, use `?` placeholders and variable binding. Replace

```
Hosts.MAC_ADDR +"=" +String.valueOf(mhost.mac_addr),null
```

with

```
Hosts.MAC_ADDR +"=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(mhost.mac_addr) }
```

The `String.valueOf` is possibly not needed.